# Why can I create new Random without the keyword "new"

Tags: scala, singleton

In my study of Scala I ran into the following snippet:

```
val r = Random
```

Now from my understanding from Alvin Alexander's excellent post ([How to create Scala object instances without using the “new” keyword (apply)](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-create-scala-object-instances-without-new-apply-case-class) you can create a new Scala object instance without using the new keyword as follows:

- Create a companion object for your class, and define an apply method
  in the companion object with the desired constructor signature.
- Define your class as a “case class.”

However, when I look at the source code for the Random class (Scala 2.12.8) I see that it is not a case class nor does the companion object have the apply method in its companion object.

Could someone please explain to me why it's valid syntax to create a Random as posted above even though it doesn't meet the requirements as described in Alvin Alexander's post?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context `Random` is a singleton instance of class `Random`

```
object Random extends Random
```

where

```
class Random(val self: java.util.Random) extends ... {
  ...
  def this() = this(new java.util.Random())
  ...
}
```

hence it is already a value. For example consider the following

```
class Foo(val v: Int)
object Foo extends Foo(42)
Foo.v
```

which outputs

```
res0: Int = 42
```

Note how `Foo` in `Foo.v` is already referencing an instance singleton value of class `Foo`. Hence `r` in

```
val r = Random
```

is simply referencing existing singleton value. It is akin to

```
val a = 11
val r = a
```

Comment: Cool, thanks my friend, now I also understand the "Random extends Random" bit :)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: you are *not* creating a *new instance* of the [`Random` *class*](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random.html), you are assigning the *existing instance* of the `Random` class which also happens to be called [`Random`](https://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/Random$.html) to the field `r`.

It might sound confusing that there is both a `class` and an `object` named `Random` but there actually cannot possibly be any confusion, since in Scala, types and terms live in different "worlds" and their names can never mix.

Note that it is in fact quite common to have a `class` or `trait` and an `object` with the same name, for the following reason:

- if an `object` has the same name as a class or trait, **and**
- that `object` is defined in the *same scope* as the `class` or `trait` with the same name, **and**
- that `object` is defined in the *same compilation unit* as the `class` or `trait` with the same name, **then**

that `object` is called a [*companion module*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#object-definitions) and has [privileged access](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/05-classes-and-objects.html#private) to the internals of the `class` or `trait`.